# Two git.exe in MSYS2

Tags: git, mingw, mingw-w64, msys, msys2

I found two binaries "git.exe" in my MSYS2 installation.

The first one is under the following path:
"\msys64\usr\bin"

The second one is under the following path:
"\msys64\usr\lib\git-core"

Can someone describe the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in [magit issue 2259](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2259) and [commit 724ea52](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/724ea52dd86629394414ae431b19e58fd6070da9),

> Git for Windows 2.x reorganized the directory structure so both cmd/git
>   and bin/git are just wrappers that call the real thing

In that case, `\msys64\usr\lib\git-core` is the actual one, the other being a copy or symlink.

Note that if you are using the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (instead of Cygwin), you won't get that kind of duplication.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using MSYS2 for my whole development. I don't think I will find all the tools with MSYS that comes with Git.